# How can i hide my Db password export via shell script during execution of program

Tags: shell

I am exporting my Db password during build my C++ project. When i run my job, Db password is visible in process list.

build.sh:    export MONGODB_PASSWORD=*************Passw0rd

During execution of my program when i am running below command, Db password is visible.

ps aux

jc185785  3493  0.0  0.0 193316  4744 pts/2    S+   Dec22   0:00 ssh -X -t houcy1-n-cp101k27 
export PS1="\u@\h:\w: "; export CDIS_INSTALL_PATH=/glb/data/cdis_projects/users/jc185785/CDIS/installed;export BUILD_TYPE=release;export WORK_SPACE=/glb/data/cdis_projects/users/jc185785/CDIS/TFS-356978; export OST_DOMAIN=americas.shell.com; 
export MONGODB_HOSTNAME=houcy1-n-sv0050.americas.shell.com:27100; export MONGODB_AUTH_SOURCE=admin; 
export MONGODB_USERNAME=cdis-domain; export MONGODB_PASSWORD=**########Passw0rd**;

Could you please suggest how can i hide to not show password.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign your password somewhere with variable and call the variable using $ VARNAME.

Comment: I should not do  **export MONGODB_PASSWORD=*************Passw0rd** rather export i should use with local variable.